# Flaked rice vs. Uncle Ben

Tags: adjuncts

I happened to do my grain shopping at a LHBS that I don't usually shop at yesterday, I was going to make a bunch of a light lager.  They didn't carry flaked rice though, so I had to double back to to my regular LHBS.

Could I have just gone to a grocery store and go plain white rice?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's fine to add any kind of rice to the mash, but the rice must be cooked to make the starches dissolvable and digestable by the amylase enzymes.

If you use minute rice, it's already been cooked, so it can be added directly to the mash.